# Removing unnecessary import from a whole project

Tags: php, linux, eclipse, replace, sed

Recently at work we had this trainee that created quite a few unnecessary files in her project, I'm on the process of cleaning up the project to try and salvage it,however, I'm on a bit of trouble.

For example, I want to delete the following lines of code from all the files in the project (thankfully they're consistent):

```
<?php
include('includes/footer.php');
?>
```

I'm open to do this on eclipse or sed, I've tried with both to no avail, I've already done in another project where I delete the include line using sed, but then I end up with a bunch of empty php tags, I hope you guys can help me find a solution that I can just use and keep in mind going forward.

Thanks

Comment: `\<\?php\s*(include[^\;]+\;\s*)+\?\>` this should catch them, might need to add multi line modifier.

Comment: Use eclipse for replacement as said in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

sed is for simple substitutions on a single line. For anything spanning multiple lines, use awk. This is using GNU awk for multi-char RS:

```
$ cat file
foo
<?php
include('includes/footer.php');
?>
bar
$ awk -v RS="^$" -v ORS="" '{sub(/<[?]php\ninclude[(]\047includes[/]footer.php\047[)];\n[?]>\n/,"")}1' file
foo
bar
```

In the search RE, it uses `[]` around RE metacharacters so they are treated as literal characters, and uses `\047` for the single quotes `'` since you can't use a single quote within a script that's delimited with single quotes.

Answer (score 0):

Use Search dialog.
Select the project in Package/Project/Navigator view then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd>

[image]

Enter the regular expression as shown in pic. Also note that I have chosen **Selected resources** option and selected `com.chandrayya....` project in package explorer.

Press **Search** button. You will get all the results in Search view.

Activate search view and press collapse all button to collapse all search results then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> to select all search results in search view. Right click on the selection and choose `Replace All..` option then you will get a dialog box as shown below. Enter once space character in **With** text box and press **OK** button.

[image]